# Set variables to client socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm making a Java TCP Server and a noob question that I can't revolve came to me, what's the way to set variables to the current client socket? Check class Handler, code above may be not important.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Handler;

public class tcp_server {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
    Socket client;

    try {
      ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);

      while(true) {
        client = server.accept();
        executor.execute(new Handler(client));
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static class Handler implements Runnable {
    private Socket client;

    public Handler(Socket client) {
      this.client = client;
    }

    public void run() {
      try {
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        String event = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println(event);

        // Arrays.copyOfRange(byte[] original, int from, int to)

        // Index
        if(event.equals("GET / HTTP/1.1")) {
          // ...
          client.close();
        }

        // Authenticate
        if(event.charAt(0) == '0') {
          String client_token = Arrays.copyOfRange(byte[] event, int 1, 33);

          // I'm gonna add the MySQL Queries later

          // if session id found on table
          String client_google = "000000000000000000000"; // MySQL
          client.session = client_token; // -> Token received from client. (?)
          client.gid = client_google; // -> Google+ Profile (?)
          // **How do I set variables to the current client?**
        }

        // Sync settings
        if(event.charAt(0) == '0') {
          // ...
          // access non static variable from here
          System.out.println(client.session); // (?)
          System.out.println(client.gid); // (?)
        }

        // More events
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }

  // End.
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to store your data local to your particular connection. 
In your example the easiest way would be to declare a session-variable which is a field of Handler, something like:

```
public static class Handler implements Runnable {
    private Socket client;  
    private UserSession session;

    public Handler(Socket client) {
      this.client = client;
      this.session = new UserSession();
    }
 ...
```

The `UserSession` can contain what you want. Another option is that UserSession class is exchanged for `Map<String, Object>`, which will hold key-value mappings local to this user connection. Minuses: if your system grows, you will have to pass the reference to this session to all the methods, which need the session data.

As long as you are using blocking IO for your data input, you can also use such a class as `ThreadLocal`, which goes out of the box with java. This mechanism does the same as your local variable `UserSession`, your session variable will be accessible in any part of your code as long as it is run by 1 thread (which is the fact for blocking IO). You can read about it here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

The last way - a non-blocking thread-pool HTTP way - send a session identifier with every request, sth like `user=login`. Next, store a large `Map<String, UserSession>` in the app context (it can be your own singleton, accessible for all threads when reading incoming data), and then retrieve the required session by request parameter (user).